# React filtering Json array //TypeError: includes is not a function

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, filtering

```
this.state.records.filter(record => this.state.id == '' || record.id.includes(this.state.id))

    .map(record=> (

         <ProjectItem key={record.id} project={record} />

         ))
```

when i doing it i getting TypeError: record.id.includes is not a function, includes is String func but my record.id does not recognize

```
  constructor(props){

  super(props)

  this.state={

    records:[],

    id:''

   };
```

i am getting records[] from axios.get()

Comment: Try placing your code in a runnable snippet (this can be inserted using `Ctrl + M`). Also, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to ask better questions.

Answer (score 2):

It means, `records` array is not empty, but somehow `id` is not defined. For example:

```
records = [
  { score: 4.5 },
  ...
];
```

Or:

```
records = [4.5, 5.5, ...]
```

The solution is checking for validity of `record.id` first before checking that it contains `this.state.id`, like this:

```
this.state.records.filter(record =>
  this.state.id == '' || (record.id && record.id.includes(this.state.id))
);
```

***UPDATE:*** *If the above still doesn't work, it could be because you're testing    it on IE. `includes` doesn't work in IE, so you might want to use    `indexOf`.*

Comment: if i do .filter(d => (this.state.id == '' || d.id==this.state.id) it s accepting but that has to be same u know so id is defined (i am using Chrome)

Comment: But, `d.id === this.state.id` still works even if it's undefined.

Comment: d.id === this.state.id it s not working

Comment: what I mean is `d.id === this.state.id` does not throw an error even if `d.id` is undefined.

Comment: ok but  when i do .filter(d => (this.state.id == '' || d.id==this.state.id) that filtering my table but i ll use it for text and if i use it my text suppose to be the same with my data base not a single character less

Comment: In the first 2 scenarios, it would throw the error *"cannot read property `includes` of undefined"* and not *"`record.id.includes` is not a function"*. OP needs to add the polyfill of `includes`.

Comment: @adiga good point. agreed.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the record variable two times. First in the outer block of filter function and second in the inner block of map function. So the compiler will not be able to identify which record variable to use and will throw an error.

You have to use another variable for map function like used in the code below.

```js
function ProjectItem(props) {
  console.log("props => ",props)
   return (
   <div>
     <h1>{props.project.id}</h1>
   </div>
    )
 
}


class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      id:'a' , 
      records: [
                  {id:"a"}, 
                  {id:"b"}, 
                  {id:"c"}, 
                  {id:"d"}, 
                  {id:"e"}, 
                  {id:"f"}, 
                  {id:"g"}, 
                  {id:"h"}, 
                  {id:"i"}
                ]
     };
  }
  
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
       {this.state.records.filter(record => this.state.id == '' || record.id.includes(this.state.id))
        .map(rec => ( <ProjectItem  key={rec.id} project={rec} />) )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: normally i am using another variable i change the name for  easy to understand in here

Comment: You can try the above code. It's working. If you run the upper snippet then you can cleary see there is nothing wrong in the include function above. It's working.

Answer (score -1):

First of all includes() is mainly used for arrays, and here you are calling this function on record.id which i guess is a string so you should be using record.id.contains(x)

Second, in js the identity (===) operator behaves identically to the equality (==) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal. So you should use the identity operator in your condition

Comment: `includes` is also valid on the String type.

Comment: id doesnt matter includes or contains. => record.id.contains is not a function now i getting this i have different problem

Comment: `string.prototype.contains` was deprecated a while back, you should *not* use it, and there is no real solution provided in your answer.