# React JS Filtering ARRAY //includes is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting includes is not a function error and already record.id not recognize .includes() on VS Code

I have no idea problem is where?

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from "axios"

export default class Tablo extends Component {
     constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      records:[],
      id:1
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        {
            this.state.records.filter(record => record.id.includes(this.state.id))
            .map(rec => (
                <li> {rec.shop}</li>
            ))
        }

        </div>
    )
}
componentDidMount() { 
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/kayitlar').then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({records:res.data});
    });
}
```

Comment: what your records are . Can you please attach the snapshot?

Comment: What does your `records` data look like? `includes` is an array function, so for `records[n].id` should have to be arrays for it to make sense. Please add the data you're working with

Comment: `.includes()` is part of the `String` and `Array` data type

Comment: If records[x]===1 then includes will not work - then you need  `this.state.records.includes(this.state.id)`

Comment: i import a photo of my records on top

Comment: Please do not post the same question again with a different account: [React filtering Json array //TypeError: includes is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59983018). 1) `id` should be a string or an array. 2) You need to add the polyfill for `includes` or use `indexOf`

Comment: Could you please show an example of the data you are testing. Where is the `records`

Answer (score 0):

The includes() method determines whether a string contains the characters of a specified string.

I think you are applying on number, so giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

Look, includes is only used for array of strings or with string comparing if a string contains part of another.

Based on that you have two options to solve your problem

1. Check if `record.id` is set and its type is string or array
2. Assuming that id's should be unique, the best way to compare them is with `==` operator